# What causes libdispatch error EVFILT_MACHPORT in MacOSX Sierra?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, macos-sierra, libdispatch

Good morning,

I am facing a crash in my application. When the user tries to start it, he waits like a minute and then a std::exception is raised. Really I could not reproduce the bug by myself, but it seems quite a common problem.

The only thing I could track is the following line in syslog:

BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked

Then, I start to google it and I can not find much more...I can only "suppose" that is some problem with [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) (that I do not use afaik, or at least not directly...). What I saw in Internet is that it is related with MacOSX Sierra. But the majority of forum have no answer, just a lot of tries without a unique result. Maybe the only web page that seems a bit clear about a workaround (that I have not tested, and anyway I do not want to use) is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/5n5723/internal_error_with_fusion_is_there_a_logfile_to/).

So...:

- someone has clear what can cause the exception in libdispatch?
- someone can give me some good link, official documentation or something?
- Is true that can be a bug in Sierra without updates?
- Could it be related with the installer of an application?
- Someone knows a way to reproduce this exception with a test program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This libdispatch log message is not fatal, and is almost certainly not related to your crash, which sounds like an abort due to an uncaught C++ exception (without a crashreport/backtrace it is difficult to say anything more). libdispatch does not itself generate any C++ exceptions FWIW.

As to the meaning of that specific log message, it relates to the following section in the dispatch_source_create(3) manpage:

> CANCELLATION:
>        Important: a cancellation handler is required for file descriptor and mach port based sources in order
>        to safely close the descriptor or destroy the port. Closing the descriptor or port before the cancellation handler has run may result in a race condition: if a new descriptor is allocated with the same
>        value as the recently closed descriptor while the source's event handler is still running, the event
>        handler may read/write data to the wrong descriptor.

If you see the EVFILT_MACHPORT "vanished" log message, somebody in your process has violated that API contract and deallocated a machport while a dispatch source was still monitoring it (causing the kernel to generate an EV_VANISHED kevent), see the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/666df60ce98b9f38814b544f9ff1ca74b7bbf70d/src/source.c#L1109).

Comment: The linux port of libdispatch on Swift actually will crash your process instead (look for EPOLLFREE in the github repo @das just linked), but sadly the Darwin port has not enforced this from day 1 so it's only a log.

Comment: not the answer I was looking for, but I suppose it is the right one...thanks